# Using POEdit to translate, but strings not always read (PHP/WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, poedit

I have experienced this with more WordPress plugins than I like.

I translate / expand the translation file. However, some translations simply do not work.

Right now I am translating a plugin for WordPress. The word "Save" will simply not appear translated no matter what I do. Most others work, but a few translations do not.

I am wondering what the possible reasons could be. My only guess so far is that the translation is somehow read from a nother translation file that has the same word defined in its index (but not translated)

However, is there any other possible explanation? The problem is driving me nuts quite often where I simply end up trying to ignore it, but that seems like a poor solution as well :)

Comment: interesting question.. i actually have found another way that translation won't be translated when that text is actually from the plugin but it was overwritten on the theme folder such as woocommerce plguin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . My only guess so far is that the translation is somehow read from a nother translation file that has the same word defined in its index (but not translated)

It's possible the file isn't being picked one for some reason (bad name, bad location, overshadowed by the same file in a higher-priority location). First step: verify that's not the case, by changing some other translation.

If that's not it, well, then [use the Source Luke!](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Use+the+Source+Luke) Go find the string in the plugin's source code. Maybe the string isn't wrapped in a gettext function at all. Maybe it is, but it is evaluated too early, before the textdomain is read. Or maybe it's read from a wrong domain. Or even from the default one. I've seen it all. The point is, nobody can check their crystal ball and tell you what the cause is *in this particular case* — it differs. You need to debug it.

But "Poedit" is a red herring, once a string is in the PO (and thus MO) and its translation is not being picked up, your problem is with the *code using gettext library* inside the plugin/theme/whatever, not the tool you happen to use to edit the translations.

Comment: I think the file is picked up because other translations are picked up. However from initial inspection of the source - that appars correct as well.

Comment: @Tom Unless you believe in magic, there aren't exactly many other explanations (unless you're omitting crucial facts). I suggest you actually *debug* the code, instead of being content with "initial inspection" (read: quick glance) than "appears" to be correct. Debug it, analyze it, *prove* that it is in fact correct. And verify that these "other translations" are picked from *this* file, not from e.g. some older copy of it (i.e. try changing them, as I said).